# What does 马大碗 (mǎdàwǎn) = "horse big bowl" mean in 马大碗拉面?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, food

This sign is on our campus's halal cafeteria:

[image: 马大碗拉面 各种面食]

It says:

> 马大碗拉面 各种面食
>
> mǎdàwǎn lāmiàn   gèzhǒng miànshí

- [拉面](http://dict.cn/%E6%8B%89%E9%9D%A2) = "pulled noodles", famous noodles in China, often from Lanzhou (兰州)
- [各种](http://dict.cn/%E5%90%84%E7%A7%8D) = every kind of
- [面食](http://dict.cn/%E9%9D%A2%E9%A3%9F) = flour-based foodstuffs (noodles, in this case)

I'm not sure what 马大碗 means here.  It's possibly a name; I'm not sure because the given name (名字) would be "big bowl".

- [马](http://dict.cn/%E9%A9%AC) = horse
- [大碗](http://dict.cn/%E5%A4%A7%E7%A2%97) = big bowl

**Question**: What does 马大碗 (mǎdàwǎn) = "horse big bowl" mean?

Comment: 马 may mean 马氏, the family name. 大碗 - big bowl; large quantity. (马氏)(大碗拉面)

Comment: Another point is that 兰州 is the capital city of 甘肃 province, where many Chinese Hui people are living. 马 is a very common family name for Hui people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

马 means 马氏, the family name.

大碗 - big bowl; large quantity.

(马氏)(大碗拉面)

The company was established in 1993.
It registered the name [马师傅马大碗](http://www.qzmstf.com/page/company.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

马大碗拉面 (Mr.Ma's Big Bowl Pulled Noodles) is the name of the restaurant.

马 is a common family name. Either the restaurant owner's last name is 'Ma' or the recipe of this noodle dish was created by someone named 'Ma'-- Most likely the owner came up with the recipe

马大碗 is either the owner's nickname-- because he serves pulled noodle in huge bowls(大碗) or  马大碗拉面  is a description of the restaurant's famous noodle - 'Big Bowl of noodle created by Mr.Ma'